Identify this 80s/ 90s sci-fi - Man with cyborg arm rips out heart
Set in America in full english, colour film, most likely late 80s early 90s movie about a guy who I seem to recall has a cyborg arm. 
There's a woman in it who is obviously in love with metal-arm and likes to see him do things like break off the corner of marble counters with his super arm.
He beats up lots of folk and the final scene is him confronting the main bad guy and saying something like: 
_"You don't own a man until you own his heart! " - He punctuates this by punching the guy in the chest and ripping out his heart. He holds it in front of the guy who, I'm sure, is thinking 'That's my heart!' before he dies.
I think it had steel or iron in the title but can't be sure. Think 'Fist of Steel' or 'Iron Arm'....maybe less so the second one.

Hands of Steel, a.k.a Fists of Steel, a.k.a Atomic Cyborg
You can watch the complete movie here: 



The woman, owner of the diner, gives odd jobs around the house to the cyborg guy, for example chopping up the woods, ca. at 0:26:25. 
Dude, I was wrong, there is a heart ripping scene. The final confrontation between the cyborg and the main baddie starts ca. at 1:23:50 in the video above, and the cyborg rips out the main bad guy's heart ca. at 1:25:20. Sorry, I saw this movie a very long time ago, I didn't really remember that scene, I wrote my earlier comment above from memory, but now I have just checked the movie on youtube and the heart ripping scene is there. Sorry again! :) This is the movie you are looking for. 

Aahh...thank you. Man, I knew it was a bad movie but I don't recall it being this bad. And my guess of 'Fist of steel' was ridiculously close to the actual title. Amazing how I hadn't found it before.
